# How to compile the C std library functions on RISC-V in a small size?

Tags: gcc, linker, riscv

I am using the [PicoRV32](https://github.com/YosysHQ/picorv32) IP Core, it works well with ASM.

And I follow its [instruction](https://github.com/YosysHQ/picorv32#linking-binaries-with-newlib-for-picorv32) of compiling and linking with the *newlib*.

The output does work, but its size is unacceptable.

Here is an example of my source code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
uint8_t str[32];
int main()
{
    for(int i=0;i<32;i++)
        sprintf((char*)str,"Hello World, %d!\n",i);

    return 0;
}
```

And I am using this [makefile](https://github.com/YosysHQ/picorv32/blob/master/scripts/cxxdemo/Makefile)

Use the following command to check the output size.

```
riscv32-unknown-elf-readelf -S firmware.elf
```

The compiled code size is 0xbbec bytes, which is way too large for me.

```
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            00000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] .text             PROGBITS        00010000 001000 00bbec 00  AX  0   0  4
```

As a comparison, this C source file compiled with ARMCC on Cortex-M0 Platform takes less than 1000 bytes. Which is about 50x smaller. I wonder if there's something wrong.

---

Update:
By doing the `nm -S --size-sort firmware.elf`

I found there are some software floating-point calculation functions in the elf.
Maybe I am going to write some basic IO functions by myself.

```
00013744 00000290 t emul
00013344 0000031c t emdnorm
000139d4 00000328 t ediv
0001b810 00000334 T __trunctfdf2
0001d60c 00000408 D __malloc_av_
00017a0c 00000410 T __umoddi3
0001d078 00000428 d impure_data
000175d8 00000434 T __udivdi3
00017080 00000558 T _realloc_r
000184ec 000005c0 T __muldf3
00014994 00000660 T _malloc_r
00017e1c 000006d0 T __divdf3
00013cfc 00000bf4 T _ldtoa_r
0001623c 00000c28 T _svfiprintf_r
00018e08 00001008 T __multf3
00019e10 00001518 T __subtf3
000105d0 00001f1c T _svfprintf_r
```

Comment: soooo `...-nm -S --size-sort firmware.elf` and find out what's so big.

Comment: And maybe now you should compare that with your `ARMCC on Cortex-M0 Platform` you mention as a reference. Anyway, research "newlib nano" and `-specs=nano.specs`.